# Can the Mah Jong force out the Phoenix as part of a straight in Tichu?

Tags: tichu

Suppose I play a straight with 1-5 and wish for a 7. The next player has a 3,4,5,7, and Phoenix.

Does my wish compel the player to complete the straight using the Phoenix and fulfill the wish, or the usage of Phoenix exempt from the wish, since the Phoenix cannot be wished for under ordinary circumstances?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the 7 is forced out in this case. The rule for the wish is that if a player has any legal play that involves playing the 7, then he must do so.

Note that if the player had 5,6,Ph,8,9; then he would NOT be forced to play that straight; because he doesn't actually have a 7.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  From the official Rio Grande rules:

> *Do I have to use the Phoenix to fullfill a wish?*
>
> Yes. The next player who has a card of the desired rank and can lawfully play it must play it. Even if
> he has to play a bomb **or a sequence of appropriate length with the Phoenix.**

Comment: Link is broken!

Comment: @Stef I can't find a Rio Grande link - but the official rules are out there in PDF format.